# Class, interfaces, or enum expected (Java)

Tags: java, class, import, enums, package

Why I import these will cause me error?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;
```

//A short demonstration example.

```
package bookpack;

class Book{
    private String title;
    private String author;
    private int pubDate;

    Book(String t, String a, int p){
        title = t;
        author = a;
        pubDate = p;
    }

    void show(){
        System.out.println(title);
        System.out.println(author);
        System.out.println(pubDate);
        System.out.println();
    }
}

class BookDemo{
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Book books[] = new Book[5];

        books[0] = new Book("JAVA: A beginner Guide", "Schidt", 2010);
        books[1] = new Book("C++ :Guide", "Adam", 2013);
        books[2] = new Book("F+", "Ben", 2014);

        for(int i=0; i < books.length; i++){
            books[i].show();
        }
    }
}
```

Why I just have to delete those (import) and it will work fine?

```
package bookpack;
^

1 error
```

I very appreciate if somebody can help me to solve my problem. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The imports should come after the package declataion.

```
package bookpack;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;

//A short demonstration example.

class Book{
...
```

Answer (score 0):

write `package bookpack;` on the top of the file , above all the imports.

Like this :

```
package bookpack;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;
//A short demonstration example.

class Book{
   ...
   ...
```

> You should read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html) before starting packages.